# Uploading fields from Excel into ArcMap Attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, attribute-table, excel

I have digitized a polygon using ArcMap 10.1.

I want to upload fields from an excel table into the attribute table of the polygon layer.

How do I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just need to add your Excel worksheet as a table.

Then as long as that table has a field that is also present in the feature class use ArcMap (or the Join Field tool) to join them.

Comment: Hi, I have no common fields in the feature class table of Arcmap..The table is empty so I can't use the join tool. Is there another way ?

Comment: I think you should research why your table is empty separately. There are many posts here about why spreadsheet data is sometimes not read properly. Without a common field I cannot see how you will know which row in the spreadsheet belongs to each feature.

Comment: If and only if you are confident that they have the same number of features and are in the same order, you could generate a unique_id field for each and then join based on that.  However, if there is no way to correlate records, there isn't much you can do. It sounds like a different approach altogether is needed.  The new approach should make use of the database abilities of ArcMap while never separating from the spatial aspect.

Comment: The way I read this, asker created new polygon features via digitizing with no attributes (identifying or otherwise, beyond defaults) at the time of creation. It's not the Excel table that's empty, it's the feature attribute table. As comments have indicated, asker needs to create an identifying attribute field for the feature class, edit the polygons to give each a unique value present in the Excel table, and *then* join. @user49710 No there is no other way. As GeoJohn indicates you *might* get away with OID being in Excel row order and just adding a id field to your spreadsheet to join on.